# Do finitely generated modules over $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ correspond with finitely generated abelian subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, modules, abelian-groups

I know that finitely generated modules over $\mathbb{Z}$ correspond with finitely generated abelian groups in $\mathbb{Z}$, but does this same correspondence occur for finitely generated modules over the ring $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and finitely generated abelian subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$?

I've tried considering the case when $n = 6$, and it appears to be true in this case and in a few others, but I'm not sure if this is true in general.

Comment: There are finitely many subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$, but there are infinitely many finitely generated modules over $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. So, no, they are not in one-to-one correspondence. Maybe I misunderstand the question.

Comment: In that case, I think I am having trouble thinking about what modules look like. To my understanding, a module is simply a vector space where the coefficients that multiply an element in that vector space are elements from a ring rather than a field. What would modules of $\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}$ look like, then? For exmaple, would the polynomial rings over $\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}$ be considered a module?

Comment: The polynomial ring $R[x]$ over any $R$ is naturally considered as an $R$-module. Other examples include cartesian products $R^n$. Your idea that a module is like a vector space, but dropping the requirement that the ring of scalars is a field, is exactly right. This leads to lots of possibilities that are not (additive) subgroups of $R$. (Also (additive) subgroups of $R$ are not necessarily modules: the ones that are are called *ideals*. $\Bbb{Z}$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb{Q}$ but not a module over $\Bbb{Q}$ - as it is a field, $\Bbb{Q}$ has no non-trivial ideals.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to say with the clause "in $\mathbb{Z}$" in your first sentence; finitely generated modules over $\mathbb{Z}$ are finitely generated abelian groups (because "abelian group" is equivalent to "$\mathbb{Z}$-module"). Finitely generated modules over $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ correspond to finitely generated abelian groups *of exponent $n$*; that is, finitely generated abelian groups $A$ such that $na=0$ for all $a\in A$.